# File-Naming "NumberFormatter+Extensions": Meaning?

Tags: swift

I have seen this file-naming in the code of somebody else: "NumberFormatter+Extensions"

Is it just a convention? Or is there something else?

**What's the background concerning the weird usage of having a "+" in your Swift file-name?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a convention in Objective-C for source **files** for extensions and categories. In Objective-C a category has the name of the class plus the name of the category in parentheses (e.g. `MyClass(MyCategory)` would have the files `MyClass+MyCategory.h` and `MyClass+MyCategory.m`). Swift extensions (categories) have no name and thus this file convention is not needed.
Since category names are not really needed in runtime there is no mapping from Objective-C category names to Swift.

Comment: True, but I've seen the file naming convention still carry forward in Swift. It lets someone looking at a project know a file contains a set of extensions to something (class, struct, whatever)

Comment: Yes, you can do this in Swift as well, but there is no convention for this.

Comment: Right. I don't think there is any rule one way or another on filenames. I'd say agree on a norm for your projects and follow it.

Answer (score 2):

It used in Objective-c when you wanted to customize existing classes, it's called `Category`, equivalent to an extension in Swift. Some people still keep this old style, however, it's not quite correct in Swift. Check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) for more details.